# How to use cv2.boxpoints or eqvt function so that its edges remain parallel to image edges?

Tags: python, image-processing, droplet

i am using cv2.boxpoints on some droplet images.The box axis is rotated with respect to image axis.Can any one help me with equivalent function or any addition to box point function that keeps box axis parallel to image axis.
This would help me to measure droplet size  along x and y axis.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) help? See section 7.

Comment: don't use `minAreaRect`. use `boundingRect`, either on masks or on contours, or on the result of boxPoints

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.